# Disable command prompt to show every training step

Tags: python, tensorflow

When I am training a model in Tensorflow, the command prompt keeps showing every training steps. May I know how can I make the command prompt to stop showing these information?

The steps are show belong.

```
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 15ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 19ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 17ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 18ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 21ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 16ms/step
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 20ms/step
```

Comment: are you using a keras model? If so, try changing the verbose level in `model.fit(..., verbose=2)`

Comment: I tried, but because I am using train_on_batch(). I cannot change it.

Comment: Share a reproducible example. tx

Comment: It may not be reproduce on your pc. I tried on another pc, and it has no problem.

Answer (score 2):

It might be late, but for those who may wonder, try this:

```
tensorflow.keras.utils.disable_interactive_logging()
```

When interactive logging is disabled, Keras sends logs to absl.logging. This is the best option when using Keras in a non-interactive way, such as running a training or inference job on a server.

[Reference](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/disable_interactive_logging)